# ag-Grid Responsive Grid - Row Values

Tags: ag-grid, responsiveness

I've seen the ag-Grid examples for responsive grids on the [ag-Grid - Grid Size](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-width-and-height/#dynamic-resizing-without-horizontal-scroll) page.

Using the "Dynamic Resizing without Horizontal Scroll" example, is it possible to expand the row in an accordion fashion to display the hidden column values for each row?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the example you mentioned here [ag-Grid - Grid Size](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-width-and-height/#dynamic-resizing-without-horizontal-scroll).
Simply don't provide width/minWidth/maxWidth to columns in columnDefs; sizeColumnsToFit() will take care of that.